# Ajax preflight http code 500 error

Tags: angularjs, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

So I have a web application build in AngularJS which is making requests to my API which is on a other domain. I've set the CORS headers etc and everything is working fine on Server A, but when I try to reach Server B which exactly the same files it return a 500 status error.

This is a screenshot of the OPTIONS request to Server A:

[image: Screenshot OPTIONS request A]

This is a screenshot of the OPTIONS request to Server B:

[image: Screenshot OPTIONS request B]

What could be wrong? It are literally the exact same files...

Answer (score 0):

It obviously has nothing to do with CORS. Error 500 is internal server error so you should start looking at you API on server B.